# Turning Parallel.ForEach() into Extension Method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I like [`ForEach()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) method, it's handy at times, on the other hand for parallel scenario we have [`Parallel.ForEach()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx).

So, for sake of consistency I created following extension method :

```
public static class ParallelExtensions
{
    public static void ForEachParallel<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
    {
        Parallel
            .ForEach(source, body);
    }
}
```

Then useage would change from standard syntax

```
Parallel
    .ForEach(listOfThings, t => DoWork(t));
```

versus extension (much easier to read) :

```
listOfThings
    .ForEachParallel(t => DoWork(t));
```

*Question* :
Just to be sure, is there something inherently wrong with this approach? I am concerned because it would have been very easy to create such method as part of TPL, and as it is not there it might be for a reason?

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong. But I would definitely not want it to be part of .NET Framework. It could stay in your project if you use it frequently.

Comment: Well maybe you are right, this way .NET stays kind of cleaner, until you need it. On the other hand EF has QueryableExtensions and methods like ToListAsync().

Comment: You can use `listOfThings.AsParallel().ForAll(x=> ...);` and use features of ParallelEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong, It's as if you wrote a "replacer". A few things to look into however.

Call Stack in case of `AggregateException` will show your extension method on top.

Handle the null parameter scenario

```
public static class ParallelExtensions
{
    public static void ForEachParallel<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
    {
       if (source == null) 
       {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
       }
        Parallel
            .ForEach(source, body);
    }
}
```

Also, in your call you can make it even prettier

Instead of

```
listOfThings.ForEachParallel(t => DoWork(t));
```

You can write

```
listOfThings.ForEachParallel(DoWork);
```

Comment: Thank's for input. "show your exception method on top", you mean "extension" method, typo?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `listOfThings.AsParallel().ForAll(x=> ...);` instead of the extension method, because in this case you can easily use [ParallelEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) methods.

For example you need to run `ForEach` for ordered array, using the extension you have to sort array before and then run `ForEachParallel`. 
Using `.AsParallel().ForAll(x=> ...);` you can add method between `.AsParallel()` and `ForAll()`

Example:

```
        var a = new List<int>();

        for(int i = 10000000; i > 0; i --)
            a.Add(i);

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        a.AsParallel().OrderBy(x=>x).ForAll(x => x = x ++);
        var timeSpent = DateTime.Now - start;

        start = DateTime.Now;
        a.OrderBy(x => x).AsParallel().ForAll(x => x = x++);
        var timeSpent2 = DateTime.Now - start;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("1 - {0} 2 - {1}", timeSpent, timeSpent2));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Or he could simply incorporate AsParallel.ForAll() call in his extension, no?

Comment: @fahadash ye, but if you add something in the extension it will affect every usage of the extension.

Comment: That would be my expectation from an extension -:)